# How do I make two texts touch each other in a column in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

So if I want to seperate two texts I would use padding, but how do I bring them so close to each other? I don't want any Space between the bottom of the "Test" and the top of the "Admin".

[image]

There is no sizedboxes or padding in between them.

[image]

Code:

```
child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: Sizes.appropriateWidth(55),
              backgroundImage:
                  NetworkImage("https://via.placeholder.com/140x100"),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: Sizes.appropriateHeight(9),
            ),
            Text(
              "Test",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display Bold',
                fontSize: Sizes.appropriateWidth(37),
                color: Color(0xFF000000),
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "Admin",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display Regular',
                fontSize: Sizes.appropriateWidth(62),
                color: Color(0xFF8D99AE),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

How do I do this in flutter? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE

You could also use the `TextStyle.height` parameter to achieve the same effect, Like this,

```
Text(
  "Admin",
  style: TextStyle(
    fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display Regular',
    fontSize: 62,
    height: 0.7,
    color: Color(0xFF8D99AE),
    ),
),
```

OR

`Transform.translate` widget to the rescue.

The `Transform` widget allows you to perform any kind of transformations while painting your child.

`Transform.translate` is the named constructor for performing a `translation` by an `Offset`. Just wrap your child and give it an `Offset` to get it working.

You can use it like this,

```
Transform.translate(
  offset: Offset.fromDirection(-pi / 2, 20),
  child: Text(
    "Admin",
    style: TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display Regular',
      fontSize: 62,
      color: Color(0xFF8D99AE),
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image]

In `offset: Offset.fromDirection(-pi / 2, 20)`, `-pi / 2` means towards the top and `20` is the distance to move.

Play with the `distance` and see what works for you.

Comment: This worked just fine with the height property. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to have helped. :) Try the `Transform` solution if some issue comes up with backgroundColor.

Answer (score 0):

There is no padding from flutter itself, the padding come from the typo, imagine you have something like `ÓÛÌmAm`, you will need extra space for those ` ^ ' on uppercase letters. You cannot get rid off this space. For solutions you can look at [Nisanth Reddy answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67650089/10286880).

Comment: Much easier solutions available than a `Stack`. Check out my answer.